# Which Xml Parser is the best option for handling xml in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I was totally confused to pickup the xml parser.Just i want to know which xml parser is the best for parsing xml efficiently in android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608647/android-best-parser-to-parse-xml-data this link will help you

Answer (score 1):

The default XML parser provider by android: XmlPullParser is really good to handle your data parsing.

For more: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) also good for XML parser (easy, relatively tiny).
The most effectively performance of course is SAX (nearly raw parser), but hard to code and control.